# How to access only one specific page YII2 (Advanced Template)?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a special case for the user in my project. if user's subscription is expired (I check this in `login action`), he will be redirected to his `profile` to edit some choices. How can I prevent him from access any page except his `profile`. This is my code in `login action`

```
 if($subPaymentType == 'free'){
                    $subHours = $data[0]['sub_hours'];

                    $minutes = $subHours * 60 * 60;
                    $start_time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $startDate);
                    $endDate = $minutes + strtotime($start_time);
                    $endDate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $endDate);

                    if(strtotime(date('d-m-Y:')) < strtotime($endDate)){
                        $model->login();
                    }else{
                        $model->login();
                        //User can access this only page only
                        return $this->redirect(['user/view/?id='.Yii::$app->user->id]);

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use AccessControl in your controller

```
yii\filters\AccessControl;



class YourSiteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login','profile'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['*'],
                    ],
                    // allow authenticated users
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],   
                ],
            ],         
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

see this guide for more  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html

and in the related actionView

```
public function actionView($id)
{
   if ($id != Yii::$app->user->id){
     // not allowed  ... perform the action you need in this case 
   } else {
      return $this->render('view', [
          'model' => $this->findModel($id),
      ]);
   }
}
```